# How Get All State Params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('offers',{
    url: '/offers?{specialOfferCode}
```

If I navigate to a URL such as:

```
/offers?specialOfferCode=10&foo=bar
```

The $stateParams returned are

```
{ specialOfferCode : 10 }
```

That is, any additional parameters get stripped off.  I cannot add more params to the defined state url because there could be a variable number of parameters and they could be named anything.

How can I get all my params in the $stateParams object, regardless of how many additional parameters there are?  (That is, I have no way of knowing in advance what my parameters might be.  All I know for certain is that there is a "specialOfferCode" parameter.)

Comment: what do you mean by `others get stripped off`? Example route shown only has the one param and isn't expecting any others like `foo`

Comment: If you have an unknown quantity and unknown keys you are likely better to pass them through alternate methods than in the url

Comment: Unfortunately you have to define each param in your state definition if you want to retrieve these params. Check this out https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/539. This might help you https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/539

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject `$location` into your controller and then use `$location.search()`. This should return the following object:

```
Object {specialOfferCode : "10", foo: "bar"}
```

Comment: This is correct. If you wanted to include the unknown variables in the toParams, then in a $stateChangeSuccess listener you can do an angular.extend(toParams, $location.search()). This will inject all extra parameters into the toParams object, however it may render that object unusable for further state changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the stateparam in your route :

```
$stateProvider.state('offers',{
    url: '/offers?{specialOfferCode}&{foo}
```